# Changing Sublime Text 3 Console Color

Tags: colors, console, sublimetext3

Where can I locate `Packages\Theme - Default\Widget.sublime-settings` in ST3 on mac?  This question is not a duplicate, please read it carefully before you relegate it to the trash.  I am well aware of how to access the packages folder.  In ST2 if you were to modify the second line to be the same as your current editor theme, the console would match.  I cannot find the Widgets.stTheme file on mac.

```
{
    // "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Default/Widgets.stTheme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Blackboard.tmTheme"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question (you spend more energy defending than explaining) but if I guess right on what you are asking then try installing the very handy [Package Resource Viewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) package and I think it will unlock the puzzle for you.